# Create JSON Dynamically using variables containing element names with Dot notation

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have 2 csv files in Azure Blob storage, I am using C# to parse these files

- The first csv file is a small file that contains a mapping from the data in the 2nd csv file to an API The records look like the below

```
csvField1, apiField1.subfield1
csvField2, apiField2
csvField3, apiField5
csvField6, apiField1.subfield2
```

- the second csv file is big so I will use stream to read it and the file has a header with the following column names
  csvField1, csfField2, csvField4, csfField5, csvField6, csfField7

I want the output to be a JSON like the below

```
{
   apiField1:{
       subfield1: value(csvField1)
       subfield2: value(csvField6)
   },
   apiField2:value(csvField2),
   apiField5: value(csvField3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workable solution with Newtonsoft.Json library:

A) Create data class for apiField1

```
class ApiField1
{
    public ApiField1(string s1, string s2)
    {
        subfield1 = s1;
        subfield2 = s2;
    }

    public string subfield1 { get;}
    public string subfield2 { get;}
}
```

B) Create data class for API record

```
class ApiRecord
{
    public ApiRecord(string[] s)
    {
        apiField1 = new ApiField1(s[0], s[5]);
        apiField2 = s[1];
        apiField5 = s[2];
    }

    public ApiField1 apiField1 { get; }
    public string apiField2 { get; }
    public string apiField5 { get; }
}
```

C) Test

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApiRecord a = new ApiRecord("0,1,2,3,4,5".Split(','));
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{"apiField1":{"subfield1":"0","subfield2":"5"},"apiField2":"1","apiField5":"2"}
```

I just test with a simple string "0,1,2,3,4,5".  In your case, you can read each line from the stream of the CSV file.

**Or, you can use a dictionary:**

```
Dictionary<string, String> apidield1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
apidield1.Add("subfield1", "value(csvField1)");
apidield1.Add("subfield2", "value(csvField6)");

Dictionary<string, Object> apiRecord = new Dictionary<string, object>();
apiRecord.Add("apiField2", "value(csvField2)");
apiRecord.Add("apiField5", "value(csvField3)");
apiRecord.Add("apiField1", apidield1);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiRecord));
```

Output:

```
{"apiField2":"value(csvField2)","apiField5":"value(csvField3)","apiField1":{"subfield1":"value(csvField1)","subfield2":"value(csvField6)"}}
```